# ASP.NET MVC Force <th> elements on same line

Tags: html, css, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am currently trying to force all elements inside of a `<th>` to be on the same line and am having issues doing so. I've reviewed many posts and the common css answer seems to be to use `style="white-space:nowrap"` on the `<th>` element.

The code for `<thead>` is below:

```
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th><h5>Some</h5></th>
                  <th><h5>Thing</h5></th>
                  <th><h5>Another</h5></th>
                  <th><h5>Thing2</h5></th>
                  <th><h5>OneMore</h5></th>
                  <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                    <h5>Thing3</h5>
                    <md-button class="md-icon-button" style="bottom: 4px;margin-left:-3em">
                      <md-tooltip md-direction="auto" class="multiple-line-tooltip">
                        Some ToolTip Information Here
                      </md-tooltip>
                      <i class="material-icons md-dark">info</i>
                    </md-button>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
```

My issue is that the info icon seems to always display below the "Thing3" h5 element. See picture below:

[image]

All help is appreciated.

Comment: `<h5>` is a block element. It will always be on its own line unless you override its display method with CSS. Personally, I would ditch the block element and just use a `<span>` and style it the same.

Comment: you could position the md-button absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A h5 is a block level element - this is by design.

Perhaps try an inline element like `<b>` instead, or use an inline style.

```
<h5 style="display:inline">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<h5>` is a block-level element. You **should** be able to resolve this by simply floating the children of the header cells to the `left`:

```css
th > * {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h5>Some</h5>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h5>Thing</h5>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h5>Another</h5>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h5>Thing2</h5>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h5>OneMore</h5>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h5>Thing3</h5>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

However, the above example replaces the `md-button` and `i` with a simple image. If the above doesn't work for you, try replacing `float: left` with `display: inline-block`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: appreciate the help- just a note that float:left did not resolve the issue- display:inline-block and display:inline certainly do though!